# Dealing with TS libraries without types or updated types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a huge fan of static type, but there are many JS libraries that either don't have type definitions or have type definitions that are out of date and therefore cause compiler errors when you try to use a newer function.

Are there any known workarounds / practices in the TS community for overcoming this hurdle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event of missing, incomplete, or broken types, IMO the best thing you can do is [make a pull request to DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

In the meantime, here are some ways of solving issues locally:

- [Use a module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) to declare types for missing modules
- Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add missing types to classes or interfaces
- Use your own custom types based off of a library's types with the appropriate corrections
- Not recommended: do something like `(lib as any).someMissingMethod()`, or put a `// @ts-ignore: explanation here` comment above the line that errors, to temporarily suppress the error.